# Why is $\mu (\left\{ x \in X : |f(x)| > \max \left\{ |z| : z \in \text{essential range of }f \right\} \right\}) = 0$ for $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Why is $\mu (\left\{ x \in X : |f(x)| > \max \left\{ |z| : z \in \text{essential range of }f \right\} \right\}) = 0$ for $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ if $f \in L_{\infty} (X, \mu)$ (i.e. the essential supremum of $f$ is finite)?

I cannot find a good explanation here to be honest, but I know that it must be so because it's been used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084720/a-problem-with-equivalence-of-two-definitions-of-essential-supremum-of-a-functio), but not explained why exactly (and I need the explanation for that)

Comment: Hint: how do you define the essential range? $L_\infty?$

Comment: Essential range of $f$: $\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \: : \: \forall_{\varepsilon > 0} \: \mu (\left\{ x \in X \: : \: |f(x) - z| < \varepsilon \right\}) > 0\right\}$ But I still don't see how this should help me, and I really need to know it immediately. Also, I already gave you the definition for $L_{\infty}$, it's the set of functions $f$ for which the essential supremum is finite i.e. $\inf \left\{ c > 0 \: : \: |f(x)| \le c \right\} < \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Set $\max \left\{ |z| : z \in \text{essential range of }f \right\}=M<\infty.$

Then for each integer $n,$ we have $\ \mu\left (|f|^{-1}((M+1/n,\infty))\right )=0$ and so by continuity of the measure, $\mu\left (|f|^{-1}((M,\infty))\right )=0.$

And since $\left\{ x \in X : |f(x)| > \max \left\{ |z| : z \in \text{essential range of }f \right\} \right\}\subseteq |f|^{-1}((M,\infty))$ it has measure zero too.

Comment: Why do we have $\mu (|f|^{-1} ((M + \frac{1}{n}, \infty))) = 0$?